# PSQL: non-trivial update and join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, psql

I am trying to update **balances** table from **liquidation_speed** table. The problem is that I need to join **campaigns** to set update criterion based on campaign id.

**balances** table: id, liquidation_speed

**campaigns** table: id, balance_id

**liquidation_speed** table: campaign_id, count

---

Here is the query I constructed, which gives an error:

```
UPDATE  balances
SET     liquidation_speed=liquidation_speed.count
FROM    liquidation_speed
JOIN    campaigns 
        ON campaigns.balance_id=balances.id
WHERE   campaigns.id = liquidation_speed.campaign_id;
```

ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "balances"
LINE 5: ...campaigns ON campaigns.balance_id=**balances.id**...

HINT:  There is an entry for table "test_balances", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

Comment: What error does this return?

Comment: I still don't understand this question. What exactly do you want to do? What is the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

The `ON` needs to apply to the columns in the `FROM` clause:

```
UPDATE balances
    SET liquidation_speed = liquidation_speed.count
    FROM liquidation_speed JOIN
         campaigns 
         ON campaigns.id = liquidation_speed.campaign_id 
    WHERE campaigns.balance_id = balances.id;
```

I just swapped the conditions in the `ON` clause and the `WHERE` clause.  `Balances` is not known in the `FROM` clause (where all the joins are).  That is why you need the additional conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution was helpful